# Incrementing values in jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc, sql-update

I have a class called DatabaseInterface where I have my tables created over there with get Customer as a method which is as follows:

```
  public static Customer getCustomer(long id) {

        System.out.println("Get customer " + id);

        Customer customer = new Customer();

        try {
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM customer where id = " + id);

            if (resultSet.next())

            {
                long cId = resultSet.getLong("id");
                String name = resultSet.getString("name");
                long tagNo = resultSet.getLong("tagNo");
                String email = resultSet.getString("EMAIL");
                String telephoneNo = resultSet.getString("telephoneNo");
                int noOfTimesRecycled = resultSet.getInt("No of Times Recycled");

                customer = buildCustomer(cId, name, tagNo, telephoneNo, email, noOfTimesRecycled);

                System.out.println(customer);
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error in getting customer");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return customer;
    }
```

I have a text file that reads value of the tagNo and each time there's a new entry for a tag it increments the value of noOfTimesRecycled.
Am doing that in a new class called UpdateTag. So I called the method getCustomer from DatabaseInterface class first and then will move on with the updates but getting error.

```
    package com.qmul.rfid.service;
import java.util.List;
import com.qmul.rfid.dataaccess.DatabaseInterface;
//import com.qmul.rfid.dom.Customer;

import com.qmul.rfid.reader.ImportTagJob;


public class UpdateTag {

List<String> fileList = ImportTagJob.fetchData();

{

    try{

         for (String tag : fileList)
         {
             DatabaseInterface.getCustomer(long id); //Getting error on long id -Syntax error on token "long", delete this token         
                    System.out.println(tag);     
         }
       } 
    catch (IllegalArgumentException ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

}
}
```

Any idea why?

Comment: "but getting error." ... wanna tell us more?

Comment: getting error at DatabaseInterface.getCustomer(long id) - Syntax error on token "long", delete this token

Comment: *"long", delete this token.* Any more questions? :)

Comment: deleting long doesn't solve the error. It says id cannot be resolved to a variable because I didn't declare it anywhere in the class. I need to retrieve the values from my customer table to be able to increment the values in one of the column. So I thought that's the only way to do it.

Comment: @Sne The error is obvious, however, to me, it's not really clear what you're trying to achieve. Suggest to take some more time, describe the problem, and edit your original posting.

Comment: @qqilihq, So basically, I have a database which contains two tables - customer and house. Customer table has a column called noOfTimesRecycled and tagNo. In a text file, I have a list of tagNo and the number of times that they appear in that file gets stored in the fiel noOfTimesRecycled. So in the updateTag class, this is what I'm trying to do! So I first call the getCustomer method from my DatabaseInterface to be able to have an update method on it.
Hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: But your code does not even attempt to update any value in the database? Hint: If you want to modify entries, you need something like `UPDATE table SET value = ? WHERE condition = ?`.

Comment: yes! Working on it! But even before doing that I was getting errors while trying to retrieve the customer table! Thank you anyway :)